# Mixed PHP with jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, iteration

I have a quick script I came up with and I was wondering if this is a bad idea.

First let me explain what I want to do. I want to create a dynamic script which will add custom AJAX calls for whatever tab element I need it to. For instance, if the user clicks on `Profile`, then I want to load `profile.php` from my files.

This is simple enough, however, I have a lot of calls, and I came up with a quick fix. I am creating an array with all the scripts I need to call in PHP, and when the page loads PHP it creates AJAX call functions from the array list:

```
<?php
$tab_options = array('home', 'profile', 'news', 'api');
foreach ($tab_options as $option) 
{
    ?>
    $(<?php echo $option; ?>).click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "_template/<?php echo $option; ?>.php",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(response){
                window.top.document.title = '<?php echo ucwords($option); ?>';
                window.history.pushState("string", "<?php echo ucwords($option); ?>", "?tab=<?php echo $option; ?>");
                $("#<?php echo $option; ?>").html(response);
            },
            error: function(){
                console.log("Problem found!");
            }
        });
    });
    <?php
}
?>
```

So in this case I would have PHP loop 4 times over the code, and create the 4 functions for me. It works well, and I am able to switch between tabs smoothly. However, I am not sure if this is good practice, or if it should be avoided.

Comment: As it is written, this yields javascript like `$(home).click(function() {...`. are there variables corresponding to `home`, `profile`, etc. or should those be string literals with CSS selectors like `'#home'`, `'.home'`, etc.?

Comment: Yes, I have created variables with those from the html `id`s. They are not just plain words, They would actually be a variable containing the string with the value of their equivalent ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, I am not sure if this is good practice, or if it should be avoided.

While I don't think it is *bad practice*, it could be simplified. One technique to simplify it is using [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate).

For example, the array of tab options could be added to a JavaScript array:

```
$tab_options = array('home', 'profile', 'news', 'api');
echo 'var tab_options = '.json_encode($tab_options).';';
```

Then add a click handler to the document and check if the *id* attribute corresponds to one of those tab options.

```
$(document).click(function(clickEvent) {
    var targetId = clickEvent.target.id;
    if (tab_options.indexOf(targetId) > -1) {
```

In that code [Array.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) is used but one could also use [Array.contains()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/contains) though it isn't supported by as many (mostly older) browsers (e.g. IE).

Then to get the equivalent of [ucwords()](http://php.net/ucwords), a solution like [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5122461/1575353) can be used:

```
var properCaseOption = targetId.replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function(letter) {
    return letter.toUpperCase();
});                    
window.top.document.title = properCaseOption;
```

With this approach, the JavaScript code is not duplicated once for each tab option. Perhaps it may not be a big issue because that code could easily be updated with the PHP code, it would yield a larger HTML/JS page size.

See a demonstration of this [in this playground example](https://www.tehplayground.com/NFabrSuwHKFF61XI) but note that the AJAX requests won't yield the pages as expected so the code to update the containers has been commented out. However I made a [phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/sb4q-3wz6) that has the response from the AJAX request utilized.

Comment: Clever mate, I appreciate the answer